# Deleting operating systems from hard drive in linux

Tags: partition, windows, opensuse

Tl;dr: I have three operating systems on my computer, two of which are corrupt and I don't want there. How do I get rid of them?

I recently bought a PC with windows on it and installed Linux OpenSuse Leap 42.2 on it. I thought I had deleted all the Windows partitions in the process, but when I boot the computer, it still gives me an option of booting Windows. Fast forward a few days, I mess with the grub file in the new operating system so that it won't boot and end up installing Leap again. Now I have three boot options: Windows, my corrupt Leap 42.2, and the new Leap 42.2. I want to get rid of Windows and the first Leap I installed. How do I do it?

Comment: Read about `grub` and learn how to delete the boot options you don't want.

Answer (score 3):

The list of possible grub options are in a config file in `/boot/grub`. Only removing the unwanted OSes didn't modified this config file. But you don't need to edit it by hand, because the `update-grub` (as root) command scans your hard disk(s) for all bootable (or seemingly bootable) OSes and reconstructs this config for you.

This reconstruction works by that the `update-grub` walks over all available partition, and tries to analyze, what is on them.

It is not clear in your case, if the partitions of the unwanted OSes were really deleted. If they weren't, you may get also extra space by deleting these unwanted partitions, and

- either re-formatting them, to use as data volumes,
- or increasing your Linux partition to reclaim the unwanted space.

In opensuse, there is a partition manager included into the Yast.